# CTRL+C and CTRL+Z signals won't block in C

Tags: c, unix, pipe, signals, signal-handling

I have written following code for a simple 3 player game in C.

Flow:

1) Ask user for winning score

2) 3 children are generated

3) Each will generate random scores and accumulate it

4) Whoever reaches winning score wins and terminates the program.

```
void sigHandler(){}
void player(char *, int *, int *, int);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd1[2], fd2[2], fd3[2], fd4[2], fd5[2], fd6[2], win;
    char turn='T';
    write(1, "This is a 3 player game with a Referee\n", 38);
    printf("Enter the winning score:\n");
    scanf("%d", &win);
    pipe(fd1);
    pipe(fd2);
    if(!fork())
        player("TOTO", fd1, fd2, win);
    sleep(1);
    close(fd1[0]);
    close(fd2[1]);

    pipe(fd3);
    pipe(fd4);
    if(!fork())
        player("TITI", fd3, fd4, win);
    sleep(1);
    close(fd3[0]);
    close(fd4[1]);

    pipe(fd5);
    pipe(fd6);
    if(!fork())
        player("TUTU", fd5, fd6, win);
    sleep(1);
    close(fd5[0]);
    close(fd6[1]);
    while(1)
    {
        signal(SIGINT, sigHandler);
        signal(SIGSTOP, sigHandler);
        write(1,"\nRefree: TOTO plays\n\n", 21);
        write(fd1[1], &turn, 1);
        read(fd2[0], &turn, 1);

        write(1,"\nRefree: TITI plays\n\n", 21);
        write(fd3[1], &turn, 1);
        read(fd4[0], &turn, 1);

        write(1,"\nRefree: TUTU plays\n\n", 21);
        write(fd5[1], &turn, 1);
        read(fd6[0], &turn, 1);
    }
}
void player(char *s, int *fd1, int *fd2, int win)
{
    int points=0, dice;
    char turn;
    srand(time(NULL));
    while(1)
    {
        signal(SIGINT, sigHandler);
        signal(SIGSTOP, sigHandler);
        read(fd1[0], &turn, 1);
        printf("%s: Playing my dice\n",s);
        dice =rand() % 20 + 1;
        printf("%s: got %d points\n", s, dice);
        points+=dice;
        printf("%s: Total so far %d\n\n", s, points);
        if(points>=win)
        {
            printf("%s: GAME OVER. I WON.\n", s);
            kill(0, SIGTERM);
        }
        sleep(3);
        write(fd2[1], &turn, 1);
    }
}
```

The issue is I am trying to block <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> signals when the program is executing but it's not working when I use following code blocks:

```
signal(SIGINT, sigHandler);
signal(SIGSTOP, sigHandler);
```

Please provide some suggestions.

Comment: `SIGSTOP` cannot be caught, perhaps you meant `SIGTSTP`. Also your signal handlers are of wrong prototype. Did you compile with warnings enabled?

Comment: Yeah warnings were enabled. I was getting unused parameter argc and argv[] warnings.

Comment: Ah sorry they're of the right prototype, lack of coffee back then.

Answer (score 1):

Better than a dummy handler is using the predefined `SIG_IGN` (ignore):

```
signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);   /* ignore Terminal interrupt signal */
signal(SIGTSTP, SIG_IGN);  /* ignore Terminal stop signal */
```

Further reading:

- [signal.h - signals](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html) (POSIX)

  > If the value of func is SIG_IGN, the signal shall be ignored.
- [signal - signal management](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/signal.html) (POSIX)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add something up to @Thomas's answer I'll just provide you a link that I myself found useful when working with signals.

https://www.usna.edu/Users/cs/aviv/classes/ic221/s16/lec/19/lec.html

P.S: As Thomas aforementioned it's a really neat and classy idea to use SIG_IGN instead of "dummy" signal handlers.

Comment: Could you summarize the linked information in case that site goes down in the future?